# Should I list every short-term contract on my CV/LinkedIn?

Tags: marketing, resume, linkedin

What's common for me as a freelancer is to contract at different companies for typically between 1-6 months. Currently, I have 8 positions under work experience on my LinkedIn, 6 of which are within this time frame. I'm very specific in their descriptions that I was contracted for this time period so that people don't get the impression I can't hold a position but I'm wondering if it can be too much to list all these positions. I think the work I have done at all these places is very relevant and I want to get it across but I can't help but feel it might be overbearing. Of course, I wouldn't want my work history to seem bare (as it would be if I only listed the salary positions I held).

Also, what would be the best practice for listing this experience on a CV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Yes and No. Will listing those project make you look unserious? Then not.

If those project were regular ones you've got and finalized, then why not.

The bottom line is that "the more the better" is not always true. If you have a good portfolio with multiple long-term projects, then I would list them as the first one. Besides them, I would mention that I worked on multiple short-term projects, such as XX, YY, ZZ,...

Comment: What would be your opinion on having separate entries for projects/roles I want to highlight and a "freelance" position where I can mention additional projects/roles/clients/etc.

Comment: Firstly, does LinkedIn support anything like this? For CV, I am not sure. Most guys suggest that CV should be 1 page long so I am not sure if you have space for that idea. The bottom line is: if it's well organized and watcher can easily review your work history, then use it. Ask your friends if they think it's easily read. Don't rely on yourself solely.

Comment: I've seen others on LinkedIn set one role under Work Experience as "Freelance" and put general descriptions of what they do there (including how long they've been freelancing for). I suppose the profile is probably the same as with the CV. It should be well-organized and easy to view.

Comment: This sounds OK. Accent on Sounds. We have to see how it looks in reality.